# Is it possible to define a dynamically named property using object literal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Consider the following

```
var a = {foo: "bar"};
```

Equivalent to

```
var a = {};
a.foo = "bar";
```

Equivalent to

```
var a = {};
a['foo'] = "bar";
```

Equivalent to

```
var a = {}
var b = "foo";
a[b] = "bar";
```

#### Is it possible to do something like

```
var b = "foo";
var a = { [b]: "bar" };
```

Such that the result would be

```
// => {foo: "bar"}
```

---

Acceptable solutions are in JavaScript or CoffeeScript

Comment: I think `a[b] = "bar"` is the only way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ES6 supports computed properties.

```
// code from my original question now works in ES6 !
let b = "foo";
let a = { [b]: "bar" };

a.foo; //=> "bar"
```

Any expression can be used within the `[]` to define the property name

```
let a = {
  [(xs => xs.join(''))(['f','o','o'])]: 'bar'
};

a.foo; //=> "bar"
```

If you need to rely on this behavior in an ES5 world, you can lean on the very capable [babel.js](http://babeljs.io/) to transpile your ES6 code to ES5-compatible code.

Answer (score 6):

## No.

There is no way to do it using object literal notation.

---

**UPDATE:** According to the [**ECMAScript standard 6.0**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer) you are now able to do the following:

```
var b = 'foo';
var a = { [b]: 'bar' };

console.log( a.foo );  // "bar"
```

However, this solution won't work in old browsers, which [*do not support ES6*](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Comment: Of course, then there's the better-left-unmentioned function that can do it at the expense of invoking the compiler each time it's run.

Answer (score 4):

JSON parse allows you to convert a JSON string into an object:

```
JSON.parse('{"'+dynamicProperty+'":"bar"}');
```

This is not exactly an object litteral, but if your objective is to enter your property name as a variable it works.

Comment: How the heck did I forget about this. Good thinking. I think you want a `:`, not a `=` though, right?

Comment: A more accurate version (to account for double quotes and other special characters in property name) would be `JSON.parse('{'+JSON.stringify(dynamicProperty)+':"bar"}')`, but at that point why not just write it in two lines (pre ES6)? (Don't mind my time machine)

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, no, there's currently no syntax for interpolated key strings in object literals in CoffeeScript; but it seems at some point this feature existed! In these GitHub issues there's some discussion about it: [#786](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/786) and [#1731](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1731).

It's implemented in [Coco](http://satyr.github.com/cup) and [LiveScript](http://gkz.github.com/LiveScript/) as:

```
b = 'foo'
a = {"#{b}": 'baz'}

# Or..
a = {(b): 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of CoffeeScript [version 1.9.1](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/commit/76c076db555c9ac7c325c3b285cd74644a9bf0d2) this works:

```
b = "foo"
a = "#{b}": "bar"
```

It compiles to:

```
var a, b, obj;

b = "foo";

a = (
  obj = {},
  obj["" + b] = "bar",
  obj
);
```

[Try it](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%20%20%20%20b%20%3D%20%22foo%22%0A%20%20%20%20a%20%3D%20%22%23%7Bb%7D%22%3A%20%22bar%22).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript

```
var a, b;
(a = {})[b = 'foo'] = 'bar';
```

CoffeeScript

```
(a = {})[b = 'foo'] = 'bar'
```

Comment: sorry, this is not an object literal.

Comment: Which is basically the same thing as the OP mentioned.

Comment: I was just giving you the most terse way to write it.

Comment: @naomik How so? `a` is an object literal, and the property "foo" is immediately set as "bar". Unfortunately, it's technically already what the OP has, just condensed

Comment: @CaseyFoster, I appreciate you trying to help, but I need it to be an object literal.

Comment: @naomik What do you mean? How is it not an object literal?

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, this is the only way that I know of. It uses `eval`. But beware, `eval` is evil!

```
var b = "foo";
var a = eval('({ ' + b + ': ' + '"bar"' + ' })');
```

This is an ugly solution. To play it safe you should not rely on this. **Don't** use it!

Comment: Why is it evil in this case? I don't understand why people think `eval` is evil 100%...

Comment: Since people don't like `eval` there is another way: `new Function("return {" + b + ": 'bar'}")()`.

Comment: @Ian Because there are very little if not no cases where `eval` is sufficiently applicable. `eval` in this case isn't even is a good solution, it's a hack.

Comment: @David That doesn't make it evil. I could understand an argument that it's "unnecessary". When people say "evil", I bet they're thinking "DANGEROUS" because that's what people on SO immediately claim when they see it. I agree it's not a "solution", but since when are hacks not solutions? In this case, it's not like it goes out and does a bunch of extra things at a **high** expense of performance. Isn't this a/the way JSON is parsed if `JSON` is not available? You didn't see people looping through all characters of a JSON string, parsing it and building an object literal that way